# How to stop the .insertBefore method from removing page breaks?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a chatbox and am using the `insertBefore()` method to append text to the chatbox. However this function removes any page breaks that existed previously. For example:

```html
bot: Item Summary, please confirm<br>
turkey breast ()) X 1   ... $5.0<br>
- Total: $5.0<br>
- to be picked up from - Jimmy John's at 3945 South State
```

turns into:

```html
Item Summary, please confirm turkey breast ()) X 1 ... $5.0 - Total: $5.0 - to be picked up from - Jimmy John's at 3945 South State
```

```js
for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
  // Build out message div
  var message = document.createElement('div');
  message.setAttribute('class', 'chat-message');
  message.textContent = data[x].name + ": " + data[x].message;
  messages.appendChild(message);
  messages.insertBefore(messages.firstChild, message); // this is the func that is ruining the formatting
}
```

When I send this same message to the console, the formatting is there.

Comment: Try using `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`